# Getting percentages for every set of results returned via SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sum, average

I want to know if there is a way to somehow find out the passing percentage of each set of the query results

```
  select testcase_execution_result
  from table_testcase_execution
  where
     campaign_session_id = any
        (
            SELECT campaign_session_id
            FROM table_campaign_session
            WHERE campaign_session_name = '{$clientsformatted}'
        )
     AND 
     timestamp between '{$stimestamp}000' AND '{$etimestamp}999'
  order by timestamp ASC
  limit $4 offset 0
```

this query returns 96 results, and what i have to do is find out what is the passing rate for each set, each hour  4 tests run and the results are stored, 1 for pass and 2 for fail.

I would like to know a way to somehow loop through these and find out what the passing rate is for each hour. somehow with the query i have above keep adding to the offset 4 to get the next set and get the passing rate of each 4 and return that. should be 24 separate percentages.

thanks!

Comment: Can you structure your query so it's on multiple lines please.  That way we can read it less painfully.

Comment: Also, add the structure of your tables.

Comment: @El Yobo, restructured the query for you.

Comment: testcase_execution_id  int(10)   
 campaign_session_id  int(10)   
 testcase_id  int(10)    
 testcase_execution_result  int(10)   
 testcase_execution_message  mediumtext   
 timestamp  bigint(20)

Answer (score 0):

something in this area:

```
 select PERC(testcase_execution_result)....
 ...
 ...
 GROUP BY timestamp between '{$stimestamp}000' AND '{$etimestamp}999'
```

Comment: hey, can you explain what are you trying to do in this query?