# in sql can i group sets of results to find out the percentage of each set

Tags: php, mysql, average

I would like to know if I do a query like this

```
Select pass_fail, timestamp 
from test_execution 
where site = 'test' and timestamp between '1234567890' and '1234567890'
```

Let's say this query returns 96 results because the timestamp are a 24 hour period and there's 4 results per hour.
With this how can I find out the percentage of pass_fail for each hour in that 24 hour period.( there's 4 results per hour in those 24 hours so 96 total how can I find how many pass for each hour )
would I need to group results?

Would I need to Limit 4 offset 0 then increase the offset by 4 each run and average each set like that?
It just seems wrong that way...any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: it seems duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363360/getting-percentages-for-every-set-of-results-returned-via-sql

Answer (score 0):

1. add an "hour" column
2. put entire query in a subselect
3. in outer select, group by hour
4. in outer select, compute the % of passes as # of passes / count(*) * 100

Comment: I can't edit the structure of the table so adding hour column is out of the question

Comment: I meant add the column to the "select" clause, not the table, like "Select pass_fail, timestamp, [compute hour here]..."